# Finding number of solutions.

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

How many solutions does this equation have

$$2 \cos^2\left(\frac12 x \right) \sin^2 x = x^2+x-2$$

where $0 \lt x \le \displaystyle\frac \pi9?$

I observed that $2 \cos^2\left(\frac12x\right)$ can be written as $1+\cos x$. Simplifying $\sin^2 x,$ we get

$$(1+\cos x)^2(1-\cos x)=x^2+x-2$$

But I don't understand what to do after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

In the given range, the left hand side is positive. How about the right side?

Comment: It is positive when x is greater than 1.

Comment: But that isn't in the given range. My concern is the sign of the right side *in the given range*.

Comment: Oh. $\frac \pi9$ is less than 1. So there cannot be any real solution.

Comment: Yeah! Done :D $ $